# Is there a way to get generic vertex attributes into OpenGL Shader builder on the Mac?

Tags: opengl, glsl, vertexdata

I'm looking for a way to develop shaders for my game engine on the Mac. I've come across the OpenGL Shader Builder app, which seemed really awesome apart from one thing. I couldn't figure out a way to use generic vertex attributes with the builder.

GLSL Shader Builder works fine with all the pre-defined OpenGL vertex attributes (gl_Normal, gl_Color, gl_TexCoord, gl_MultiTexCoordX etc.), but I want to be able to define my own vertex attributes in the shader, and then have some way of passing in a set of generic vertex data which makes up a model. That way I would be able to develop the shaders independently using the GLSL shader builder, so long as I have a set of vertex attributes to pass in to the shader.